# How to get the first digit of the fractional part of a decimal number?

Tags: python, pandas

In my pandas, data is like this:
[image]

(The original data is like `2.1, 3.7, 5.6`, without the 0 following.)

I want to see the distribution of the first digit of the decimal part. (i.e, `6 for 4.6`). How can I do it?

I thought about `15.1 % 1`, but it returns `0.09999999999999964` instead.

Comment: To all the answerers:  as the OP mentions pandas, it may be desirable to enclose in apply/lambda.  E.g. `df.apply( lambda x: your_code )`.  It would also be good for the OP to be more explicit:  `df=pd.DataFrame( [0.5,4.6,7.2] )`

Comment: @UmaKanth, that's really impressive....

Comment: @JohnE you're so sweet, so considerate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For positive numbers, You could use the multiplication first, and then a modulo.

```
x = 15.6
x *= 10 # 156
x %= 10 # 6
```

If they are Negative,

```
def get(x):
    return (x * 10) % 10
x = - 15.6
print get(abs(x))
```

---

A much cleaner way as poke suggested.

```
abs(x * 10) % 10
```

---

If you have a dataframe called df, could enclose like this:

```
df.apply( lambda x: abs(x * 10) % 10 )
```

Comment: I'm actually not a python developer. You could actually edit my answer if you want to add any detail. I would appreciate that very much.

Comment: `abs(x * 10) % 10` works for both positive and negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
int(str(x).split('.')[1][0])
```

This would convert to a string, split on . and take the first character of the second part then turn it back to an integer.  The reason that you get the strange value is that 0.1 is an irrational number in binary.

You could also use:

```
int(x * 10.0) % 10
```

This would ensure that you had an integer, (you might need to use `math.round` as well).

As an example:

```
>>> pf = pandas.DataFrame([0.5, 4.6, 7.2, 9.8, 36.0])
>>> pf
      0
0   0.5
1   4.6
2   7.2
3   9.8
4  36.0
>>> pf[0]
0     0.5
1     4.6
2     7.2
3     9.8
4    36.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
>>> pf.apply(lambda x: int(x[0]*10.0)%10)
0    5
dtype: int64
>>> pf.apply(lambda x: int(x[0]*10.0)%10, 1)
0    5
1    6
2    2
3    8
4    0
dtype: int64
>>>
```

On testing for -ve numbers:

```
>>> pf = pandas.DataFrame([0.5, 4.6, 7.2, -9.8, 36.0])
>>> df = pf.apply(lambda x: int(x[0]*10.0)%10, 1)
>>> df
0    5
1    6
2    2
3    2
4    0
dtype: int64
>>> df = pf.apply(lambda x: int(abs(x[0])*10.0)%10, 1)
>>> df
0    5
1    6
2    2
3    8
4    0
dtype: int64
>>>
```

So our final answer is:

```
pf.apply(lambda x: int(abs(x[0])*10.0)%10, 1)
```

I also tried the string method:

```
>>> pf.apply(lambda x:int(str(x[0]).split('.')[1][0]), 1)
0    5
1    6
2    2
3    8
4    0
dtype: int64
```